# connection between non-orientable manifolds and torsion in 1D (co) homology

Tags: torsion, homology, cohomology

I'm interested in understanding the probability that given a prime $p$, $p$ divides the order of the torsional part of $H^k(X,Z)$, where $X$ is a finite simplicial complex.

Lets say you have a uniform distribution over all finite simplicial complexes on $n$ vertices. Given $p > 0$  what is the probability the complex you get has $H_K(X,Z)$ or $H^K(X,Z)$ having $p$ torsion?

Comment: $H^1(X)$ with integer coefficients has no torsion. 

Comment: Look at the cohomology-homology universal coefficient theorem. 

Comment: What does probability mean here?  Are you putting some distribution on finite simplicial complexes?

Comment: Matthew, it sounds like he wants some precise measure of the distribution of torsion in the (co)homology of a random collection of simplicial complexes.  Presumably 2-torsion is the "most common" but perhaps rhl wants to quantify that statement somehow. 

Comment: indeed. lets say you have a uniform distribution over all finite simplicial complexes on $n$ vertices. Given $p \in Z$ what is the probability the complex you get looks like $Z^n \times Z_{np} \times \ldots$ 

I said cohomology, but I'm interested in both/either homology and cohomology. 

Should there be more spaces with torsion then without? 

If I uniformly sample from a space with torsion, is a particular type of torsion more likely than others?


Comment: @rhl: Your reformulation in the above comment looks much better than the original question. I suggest that you edit your question (click on "edit"), and also remove the vague sentence "being a space that has a non-orientable manifold with some other stuff glued/attached to it somehow?".